# Bash date command invalid date

Tags: linux, bash, fedora

In linux bash when I enter `date -d "1986-01-01"` it shows error

```
date: invalid date "1986-01-01"
```

when `date -d "1986-01-02"` it works

when `date -d "1987-01-01"` it also works

Why `date -d "1986-01-01"` shows error in Linux Bash shell.

I am using Fedora 16

Comment: And something like `date -d "1986-01-01" "+%Y"`?

Comment: It doesn't work shows same error

Comment: i have fedora 12, 14 and 15 and they are not showing such error. so i believe it's specific to f16

Comment: Uhms, sounds pretty strange. My Ubuntu 12 gives no problem in this. Just in case, check `man date` and check if it contains any definition of date range. Maybe this question could get a better solution in [su].

Comment: Which timezone are you using? What happens if you enter `TZ=UTC date -d 1986-01-01`?

Comment: My time zone is Kathmandu,Nepal

Comment: I can reproduce your problem with `TZ=Asia/Kathmandu date -d '1986-01-01'`. Most likely it has something to do with the fact that Nepal changed the timezone in 1986.

Comment: Well done, @nosid, I think you should post this comment as an answer, as it seems to be the point. I get an `invalid date` from `1986-01-01` to `1986-01-01 00:09:59`. `1986-01-01 00:10:00` is already OK.

Comment: @nosid thank you, I got right answer.

Comment: Editing this original question made it confusing because all the answers are very specific to the Kathmandu date. please undo this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nepal changed its timezone at the beginning of 1986. The following table is copied from the *tzdata* package:

```
# Zone  NAME            GMTOFF  RULES   FORMAT  [UNTIL]
Zone    Asia/Kathmandu  5:41:16 -       LMT     1920
                        5:30    -       IST     1986
                        5:45    -       NPT     # Nepal Time
```

That means that on Jan 1 1986 the time from 00:00:00 to 00:14:59 is not valid. The following two commands show, that the first day of 1986 started with 00:15:00:

```
$ TZ=Asia/Kathmandu date -d '1985-12-31 23:59:59' '+%s'
504901799
$ TZ=Asia/Kathmandu date -d '1986-01-01 00:15:00' '+%s'
504901800
```

So the error message of `date` is correct. The date is invalid in this timezone. I am not sure what you are doing with the result of this command. However, you can try to use UTC because all dates are valid and unambiguous in UTC:

```
$ TZ=UTC date -d '1986-01-01'
Wed Jan  1 00:00:00 UTC 1986
```

Comment: Thank you I got answer in details

Answer (score 0):

I think you are  using alphabet "O" in upper case instead of number "0" in the command :)